# Trace calls to external assembly to create correct unit test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

I am linking my application to a 3rd party library. Now I have found a bug within this module and I can even reproduce it in the application. To make an example for the developers of this module I am now doing a unit test but the error does not show up.

Then I discovered Tracepoints in Visual Studio. Is there a way to trace all calls going into the 3rd party lib? Is Intellitrace (Visual Studio 2010) of any help here?

That way I could create a precice unit test for the developers of the 3rd party lib.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trace all calls to an external assembly using [Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me).